Weird behaviour with ternary switching out the same button component in React causing form to submit
When we use a ternary to swap out a button with type="button" for a button with type="submit" in a form in React, the swapped-in button causes the form to submit.
import {useState} from "react";


function App() {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsClicked(true)
    };

    return (
        <form action='/submitted'>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="John"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>{' '}
                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe"/>
            </div>
            {isClicked
                ? <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                : <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default App


But if we split the ternary into two conditionals the form will not be submitted
import {useState} from "react";


function App() {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsClicked(true)
    };

    return (
        <form action='/submitted'>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="John"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe"/>
            </div>
            {isClicked ? <button type="submit">Submit</button> : null}
            {!isClicked ? <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button> : null}
        </form>
    )
}

export default App


Also, if the swapped component is not the same component type, it won't be submitted.
import {useState} from "react";

const SubmitButton = () => <button type="submit">Submit</button>;

function App() {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsClicked(true)
    };

    return (
        <form action='/submitted'>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="John"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe"/>
            </div>
            {isClicked
                ? <SubmitButton/>
                : <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default App


React is trying to do something clever here, but can anyone explain why this happens?
I can understand that the new element is swapped in when the onClick handler is triggered. However, I don't understand why the new element is treated as having been clicked when it clearly hasn't been.

In the last code example you define SubmitButton as a simple html button without type="submit". I think this is why it doesn't trigger a submit in this example.

@TinouHD The default type for button elements is type="submit"; I'll add it for clarity, though.

mb you're right, thanks for noticing this to me

Looks like it has to do with React's reconciliation process and the diffing algorithm: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

DOM Elements Of The Same Type
When comparing two React DOM elements of the same type, React looks at the attributes of both, keeps the same underlying DOM node, and only updates the changed attributes.

When we use a ternary, the elements are considered to be the same node, so when the elements on both sides of the ternary match, React will update the previous node in place.
React docs state that the recommended remedy for this is to put keys on the elements, as @TinouHD stated in their answer.

When children have keys, React uses the key to match children in the original tree with children in the subsequent tree.

That's why this will work:
{isClicked
    ? <button key="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    : <button key="button" type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>}

The submit triggering on click is not a React-specific issue see this pure HTML and JS:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Swap button pure JS demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit="alert('submitted with swapped attribute')">
        <button type="button" id="button">Click me</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.target.setAttribute("type", "submit");
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>


You can fix this issue using React key property.
React use this property to keep tracking of elements at the same level in the components tree.
import {useState} from "react";


function App() {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsClicked(true)
    };

    return (
        <form action='/submitted'>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="John"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>{' '}
                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe"/>
            </div>
            {isClicked
                ? <button key="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                : <button key="button" type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default App


Ah, interesting! I thought that was only for loops.

You already have found solutions but I think what you need is the explanation.
Reason: "Event Propagation and binding"
Explanation:
Imagine, you have a form with a submit button which on clicking should send the form data to the server. In your case however, the submit button comes when another button is clicked. In your first code snippet, both the buttons have already been rendered by react. The only difference is that one of them is being shown to you on the basis of isClicked. The form is binded to the submit button under the hood.

What's happening here is that when you click on the first button, the
click event propagates down to the form.

When it reaches the form, React finds the submit button
that triggered the click event (Which is already revealed when you
clicked on the other button) and finds it.

Hence, it triggers the form to submit.


Why splitting the conditions worked?

When you split the conditions, the submit is not rendered and present in the initial render

Since, there is no submit button bound to the form this time (When you used ternary the button was there, rendered, bound but hidden due to condition), the event does not propagate down to the form


Hope you liked the explanation, it was an interesting scenario and question and took some testing to figure this out.
